# debian doesn't boot because of grub failures

Tags: debian, boot, grub

I have a pc with debian 9.4 inside, it worked but due to a lack of space, I decided to change of SSD, installing a bigger one. The disk system was LVM.
I could not swap of disk within debian, because I was not able to unmount /home (there always were applications using it, even after a reboot). So I created a live fedora USB and follow some tutorials (using pvcreate, vgextend, pvmove etc).
It succeeded but after that there was a last step, modify the grub, and I was not able to do that. Not worried, I decided to start my computer with the "boot repair disk" but it did not succeeded either.

here is its summary : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Dh2vqybC28/

the disk system management is LVM (I don't know if it is the reason of the boot stopping at startup, leaving me with a blinking cursor, without any message).

What could I do to get this working again?

thank you

Comment: Why did you modify grub? I don't think you need to do that. Can you link to the tutorials you followed to do this?

Comment: ok, it's here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/161279/how-do-i-move-my-lvm-250-gb-root-partition-to-a-new-120gb-hard-disk.